# Will Closing My Admob Account Crash my App

Tags: android, admob

So this is my first Android app. I made a mistake and set up my Admob account as an individual when my App operates under my company. So, after doing the research it appears that once I establish an Admob account I can't change the type (from individual to entity).

So I have to close it and create a new account. But I was wondering if I need to remove all the Admob code from my app before I close the account? Or can I just leave it be and once the account is closed the Admob SDK will just ignore the request to serve an ad since the account would be null.

I don't want to close the account and the activity of Admob searching for an invalid account causing the app to crash. However, I don't want to roll out a whole new app version if I don't have to. I'll have to roll out a new version anyway once I square away a new Admob account.

My gut tells me Admob would just ignore it and not crash the app, but I don't want to assume since my level of expertise it not that high in this area. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge, if you have caught events in your code like not internet, or failed ads loading, then deleting your Admob account doesn't affect anything, it's just like you wrote the wrong id, your app still works normally